# Convert UTC datetime to local datetime with timezone

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataframe that contains the columns `start_time` and `timezone` (example shown below).  The `start_time` is recorded in UTC.  I want to create a new column called `start_time_local` that contains the start time within the local timezone for that record.

I've tried many examples including `format()`, `force_tz()`, `with_tz()`, etc, but most examples I've seen show how to convert ALL timestamps to the same timezone, and not each timestamp to it's respective timezone

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|     start_time      |      timezone       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-07-07 16:01:15 | Europe/Dublin       |
| 2020-07-07 21:01:28 | America/Los_Angeles |
| 2020-07-20 12:45:33 | America/New_York    |
| 2020-07-24 16:00:32 | America/Los_Angeles |
| 2020-07-09 14:00:39 | Europe/London       |
| 2020-07-16 20:30:30 | America/Los_Angeles |
| 2020-07-29 14:03:09 | Europe/London       |
| 2020-07-27 20:59:32 | America/Los_Angeles |
| 2020-07-20 16:09:54 | America/Denver      |
| 2020-07-21 09:51:04 | Europe/Dublin       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

```
# example data
df <- structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1594162875, 1594180888, 
1595274333, 1595631632, 1594328439, 1594956630, 1596056589, 1595908772, 
1595286594, 1595350264), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    timezone = c("Europe/Dublin", "America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York", 
    "America/Los_Angeles", "Europe/London", "America/Los_Angeles", 
    "Europe/London", "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Denver", 
    "Europe/Dublin")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot have different time zones within a single POSIXct vector, because the timezone is stored as a single atomic attribute that applies to the whole vector. If you try to write multiple timezones to this attribute, the S3 methods for POSIXct will stop working.

If this is something you are very keen to pursue you can write a new S3 class to handle this kind of problem. The very bare bones of such a class would look something like this:

```r
POSIX_multi_tz <- function(UTC_times, time_zones)
{
  structure(as.numeric(UTC_times), 
            class = c("POSIXmulti", "POSIXt"), 
            tz = time_zones)
}

format.POSIXmulti <- function(x, ...)
{
  unlist(mapply(function(a, b) {
    format(as.POSIXct(a, origin = "1970-01-01"), tz = b, usetz = TRUE)
    }, a = x, b = attr(x, "tz"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}

print.POSIXmulti <- function(x, ...)
{
  print(format(x, ...))
}
```

This would allow for the following behaviour:

```
df$new_time <- POSIX_multi_tz(df$start_time, df$timezone)

df
#>             start_time            timezone                new_time
#> 1  2020-07-08 00:01:15       Europe/Dublin 2020-07-08 00:01:15 IST
#> 2  2020-07-08 05:01:28 America/Los_Angeles 2020-07-07 21:01:28 PDT
#> 3  2020-07-20 20:45:33    America/New_York 2020-07-20 15:45:33 EDT
#> 4  2020-07-25 00:00:32 America/Los_Angeles 2020-07-24 16:00:32 PDT
#> 5  2020-07-09 22:00:39       Europe/London 2020-07-09 22:00:39 BST
#> 6  2020-07-17 04:30:30 America/Los_Angeles 2020-07-16 20:30:30 PDT
#> 7  2020-07-29 22:03:09       Europe/London 2020-07-29 22:03:09 BST
#> 8  2020-07-28 04:59:32 America/Los_Angeles 2020-07-27 20:59:32 PDT
#> 9  2020-07-21 00:09:54      America/Denver 2020-07-20 17:09:54 MDT
#> 10 2020-07-21 17:51:04       Europe/Dublin 2020-07-21 17:51:04 IST
```

Beware though - you would still have a bit of work to do to be able to use this class the way you would use POSIXct objects. You can still use arithmetic functions to add and substract seconds, but if you use the `lubridate` package or similar, many of the methods will not work for this class unless you define various `Ops` to handle adding durations, periods etc.

Comment: `\`[.POSIXmulti\` <- function(x, i, ...) structure(unclass(x)[i], class = c("POSIXmulti", "POSIXt"), tz = attr(x, "tz")[i]);`.

Comment: `\`[[.POSIXmulti\` <- function(x, i, ...) { stopifnot(length(i) == 1); x[i]; }` (*hack*, not sure of a better way to augment `[[` methods)

Comment: Unfortunately functions like `rev` and `sort` strip many/most/all attributes, so `"tz"` is lost.

Comment: this looks appealing enough that it might be popular in its own right. Interested in working on a package with this? I can think of several times where I've "accepted" R's single-TZ execution ... and while I'm comfortable enough with it, I feel it would be really useful to optionally retain individual zones.

Comment: `sort.POSIXmulti <- function(x, decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA, ...) x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)]`

Comment: `rev.POSIXmulti <- function(x) if (length(x)) x[length(x):1L] else x`

Comment: @r2evans bravo! The subsetting operators in particular are vital. It would also benefit from an `as.POSIXmulti <- function(x) useMethod("as.POSIXmulti")` generic. The hard part for me would be getting it to work well with lubridate and ensuring it works well with plotting methods. All very tractable problems of course. Happy to chip in if you want to start a repo on your Git.

Comment: More ... I can't get it to display correctly in a frame (or tibble or DT), I'm just seeing `1.59e+09` ... but most operations still work with the above. My other concern is for things that are not aware inadvertently stripping the `"tz"` attribute, a not-uncommon thing to do in some tools. Do you know what `str` is using to format?

Comment: @r2evans so my reprex doesn't print the df as per the answer? The attribute stripping is a problem with POSIXct itself. I often get caught out with this using e.g. `sapply`

Comment: I'm finding `str.default` would need a method, not sure why `data.frame` isn't showing right for me. (It looked good for you, so I don't know what's stripping it. I'm also in a debugger at the moment, so it's possible I have some namespaces out of whack.)